# Snake bite episode, strange dream, strong man - mysterious episode

Tags: story-identification, tv

It will be very difficult.

My memory is interesting again, but I don't remember many details. It is an episode of a TV series (rather episode) from the 80s or 90s, probably made in USA. At the beginning, some guy dreams a nightmare in which he was bitten by a snake. He tells this dream to his wife or girlfriend, but then it turns out that it was sort of true after all. He lifts up his shirt, and there at the height of his hip, as it were, he has a snake bite mark.

I think that it wasn't horror movie, but something in style fantasy / mystery.

Comment: So, sort of a "your mind makes it real" scenario then?

Comment: Yes, it was something like "Beyond Belief: Fact or Fiction" (1997 - 2002) , perhaps an episode from this TV series, but I'm not sure.